# Can CUDA kernels be virtual functions?

Tags: c++, cuda, polymorphism, virtual-functions

The question is quite straighforward, but let me give an overview of my framework. I have an abstract class `AbstractScheme` representing a type of computation (a kind of discretization for an equation, but this is not important).
Each implementation has to provide a method to return the name of the scheme and has to implement a protected function which is the CUDA kernel. The base abstract class provides a public method which calls the CUDA kernel and returns how long it took for the kernel to be completed.

```
class AbstractScheme
{
public:
    /**
     * @return The name of the scheme is returned
     */
    virtual std::string name() const =0;

    /**
     * Copies the input to the device,
     * computes the number of blocks and threads,
     * launches the kernel,
     * copies the output to the host,
     * and measures the time to do all of this.
     *
     * @return The number of milliseconds to perform the whole operation
     *         is returned
     */
    double doComputation(const float* input, float* output, int nElements)
    {
        // Does a lot of things and calls this->kernel().
    }

protected:
    /**
     * CUDA kernel which does the computation.
     * Must be implemented.
     */
    virtual __global__ void kernel(const float*, float*, int) =0;
};
```

I also have a couple of implementations of this base class. But when I try to compile with nvcc 7.0, I get this error message referring to the line where I define the function `kernel` in `AbstractScheme` (the last line in the above listing):

```
myfile.cu(60): error: illegal combination of memory qualifiers
```

I could not find any resource saying the kernels cannot be virtual functions, but I have the feeling this is the problem. Can you explain the rationale behind this? <del>I clearly understand how and why `__device__` functions cannot be virtual functions (virtual functions are pointers to actual [host] functions stored in the object, and you cannot call such a function from within device code), but I'm not sure about `__global__` functions.</del>

EDIT: the part of the question which I striked out is wrong. Please look at the comments to understand why.

Comment: `__device__` function can be virtual: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#virtual-functions

Comment: `__device__` functions can be `virtual`.  The programming guide even [gives some examples](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#derived-class).   I think maybe what you are referring to is that an object, created on the host, with `virtual` functions, [cannot be passed to the device](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#virtual-functions).

Comment: Right. What you cannot have is an object which lives both in the host and in the device and has virtual functions. Or you cannot have virtual functions which are both `__device__` and `__host__`. But I might be wrong so feel free (and encouraged) to correct me.

Comment: And, by "lives both in the host and and in the device" I mean that it gets copied from one memory to the other, or passed as argument to the kernel.

Comment: You can have a virtual function which is both `__host__` and `__device__`  What you can't do is exactly what I said, instantiate an object with virtual functions on the host, then pass it to the device.  Because the object virtual function table gets filled in with host (function) pointers.  Those host pointers are meaningless when the class gets copied to the device.

Comment: I meant when the *object* gets copied to the device.

Comment: You may be able to accomplish something similar with ordinary virtual wrapper functions which call the kernels.

Comment: Don't you want to edit your question? Two people already told you `__device__` functions can be `virtual`. Which is in contrast with you claiming "I clearly understand how and why `__device__` functions cannot be virtual functions".

Comment: Correcting the question with the correct statements would mean adding something which is not directly linked with the question itself, so I decided to strike through and refer to the comments which now contain the right information. Thanks all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kernels can't be members of classes in the CUDA object model, whether virtual or not. That is the cause of the compile error, even if it isn't particularly obvious from the error message emitted by the compiler.